# Compilation of catkin work space fails on beaglebone black

Tags: ros, catkin, beagleboneblack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all

I am running debian 8.7 on the beaglebone black and i am following these [instructions](https://gist.github.com/mhaberler/621bc9df63a8f5800b64#file-ros-bb-jessie-sh-L9) to help me get ROS installed and running.

Everything is working fine until the final step where the catkin workspace is created. It fails with the following errors:

```
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
ros_comm/roscpp/CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'ros_comm/roscpp/CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/subscriber.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ros_comm/roscpp/CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/subscriber.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8823: recipe for target 'ros_comm/roscpp/CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ros_comm/roscpp/CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

Can anyone help me out in resolving this error ?
Many thanks in advance.

If anyone has a better suggestion in getting ROS installed on the BBB, please do share with me, I have tried many threads and posts but all are outdated and i am unable to get OS images for the specified methods.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280636/compilation-of-catkin-work-space-fails-on-beaglebone-black/) by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:\

> ```
> c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
> ```

These sort of errors typicaly come up when your system has run out of memory.

Do you have swap enabled?

**Comment by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) on 2018-01-24**:
thank you for your reply
no i do not have swap enabled on the BBB. I will try doing that and report my results.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-25**:
I would recommend a topic change btw: *compilation* of your workspace fails. Creating the workspace itself (which is essentially just a directory) does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello friend, I regret to say that I have little experience installing ROS in different embedded systems that are not officially supported. But I have been fighting for a long time with the problems that arise in Raspberry PI and I do not recognize any of them in the error that you present.

I know it does not solve your problem but I could recommend you change the platform, for an embedded system with more documentation like a Raspberry PI or an embedded computer. You can even find a [memory](https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com/pi.html) with Ubuntu and ROS preinstalled.

I hope I could have helped you even if it was a little

---

Originally posted by [fhfonsecaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/28517/fhfonsecaa/) with karma: 90 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) on 2018-01-24**:
Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. Unfortunately I need the BBB because of its ability to handle analog signals as compared to  the Rasberry pi.

I will also try Ubuntu on it as you suggested.